# How Can I use two differents CSS backgrounds in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

I would like to change the background based on a boolean.

If I have two backgrounds in CSS:

```
.background {
  background-image: url('../assets/images/Background.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  }
  background-size: 100% 670px;

  @media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    background-size: 100% 800px;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
    background-size: 100% 1200px;
  }
}

.performance-background {
  background-image: url('../assets/images/Background-performance.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  }
  background-size: 100% 335px;

  @media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    background-size: 100% 325px;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
    background-size: 100% 325px;
  }
}
```

I would like to use something similar to:

```
[ngClass]="{ 'background': displayBackground, 'performance-background': displayPerformanceBackground}"
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add different classes depending of a boolean state using angular ngClass and a ternary operator in a HTML tag

example:

HTML:

```
 <div [ngClass]="boolean ? 'trueClass' : 'falseClass'"> Example Text</div>
```

"boolean" is a variable and if it is set to true the html tag will use "trueClass" class, else "falseClass"

CSS:

```
.trueClass{
background: red
}

.falseClass{
background:blue
}
```